# Double semi-colon in batch file

Tags: cmd, path

What is line 2 designed to do?

```
PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%FTPCABin%;%FTPAutoSysBin%;
PATH=%PATH:;;=;%
```

PATH is the same, before and after line 2 executes.

Answer (score 2):

If FTPCABin is not defined, then your PATH will have an empty paths in the definition (consecutive path delimiters `;;`).

```
path1;path2;path3;;path5
```

I don't think it is necessary, but the 2nd line simply replaces consecutive `;;` with a single `;`. If `;;` does not exist, then there is no change.

Comment: Will there be a problem with having a double semicolon in the PATH var? I wrote a BAT script to automate some software installs and I noticed some calls to setx were inserting ";;".

Comment: @user208145 - I've never seen an issue with having empty paths (`;;`) within PATH. I would try to avoid them, but I don't think they will do any harm.

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista, you can remove the current directory from the implicit search path in CMD and `CreateProcess` by defining the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`. Note that `CreateProcess` passes its executable search path (including the application and system directories) to `SearchPath`, for which ";;" explicitly searches in the working directory. So it's always a good idea to remove these entries. You can explicitly add the working directory without ambiguity by including "." somewhere in `PATH`.

Comment: @eryksun - Way cool piece of info about that env. variable :-) I had never seen anything like it before. I tested using the Win 10 console, and it indeed works! However, `;;` in the PATH was not interpreted as the current directory. But `.` of course is treated as the current directory.

Comment: It's only a problem with the search in `CreateProcess`, which relies on `SearchPath` with a custom executable search path. CMD implements its own search that ignores empty ";;" entries.